# How to add <span> within CodeMirror editor?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

No jQuery please!

I'd like to add a styled span within the body of a CodeMirror editor. This is for the purposes of a mail merge like application where you can for instance do: (From Zapier)
[image: example]

I believe this may be possible using a CodeMirror Widget but I'm lost as to what direction to go in. I found an example of something similar (albeit far more complicated) [here](https://gist.github.com/jasongrout/5378313).

I also tried [tagify](https://yaireo.github.io/tagify/#section-mix) which is extremely similar to what I'm after but doesn't have multi-line inputs, which is a requirement.

All I need is the ability to add and remove (via backspace with the caret just behind the tag) these spans but there doesn't appear to be a simple solution.

Also if there is a convenient library or some other direction I can go in not involving CodeMirror that'd also be fine.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with CodeMirror unless it provide the API for this (because if you add something like this to DOM when Codemirror change state or refresh your span will disappear), search the library if it have such feature. If it don't provide something like this then the only option is to create your own editor or modify codemirror source code. If you don't need any extra features I would pick smaller library then codemirror that have lot of code to read before you can adding something this.

Comment: @jcubic [Maybe this is appropriate](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#mark_replacedWith), although you may be right on needing to make my own. Does seem like a small thing to have to reinvent the wheel over though.

Comment: Looking at your screen this is not something that is common or reinventing the wheel, you just have simple textarea with custom tag with css inside, If I would need create something like I would never think of using codemirror for for this unless you need source code highlighting line numbers and make it more less on mobile. This is perfect example of something that you need to do from scratch, because it will take months to investigate codemirror to add such feature, and from scratch it will take much less time to create if you don't need any fancy stuff from codemirror.

Comment: But looking at your API link you can try it, you will need to select range using the API and then insert maybe span with attributes that will show up in ::before and ::after with css. IMO it will be overkill to use codemirror.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CodeMirror is actually well suited for this.

First insert some placeholder into the document, such as [[tag]].

```
var lineNumber = 0;
var charNumber = 0;
var snippet = "[[tag]]"
editor.doc.replaceRange(snippet, {line:lineNumber, from: charNumber});
```

Then create your DOM element, I recommend a span.

```
var htmlNode = document.createElement("span");
//Style and add what you like to the span
```

Then use `doc.markText` to replace it with that node.

```
editor.doc.markText({line: lineNumber,ch: charNumber}, {line: lineNumber,ch: charNumber + snippet.length}, {
   replacedWith: htmlNode
})
```

Comment: You can use `editor.doc.setBookmark` to do this directly, without inserting placeholder text.

Comment: `markText` will make the widget one character unit wide, and leave `[[tag]]` in `editor.getValue()`; `setBookmark` is zero character units wide, and does not affect `editor.getValue()`.